# S3, Paperclip, Heroku, and iPhone app

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

Does Paperclip store url of the path to the S3 bucket in the db?  I am trying to reference the image in my iPhone app and need to upload the image (profile pic) to the phone.

Do I get User.image_url (a path to the file) and pull it in that way. Or do I pull a BLOB of the actual image (assuming Paperclip stores the image as a blob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it stores it in the db.

```
User.image(:large)
```

You need to declare a size and that is how the URL will get populated:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large=> "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```